# How to count doubles in C?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am working through the C programming language book. So this program is supposed to count each iteration of getchar(). If I type a double (2.3 and 1.8), then CTRL + D, it outputs 8. Why is that? shouldn't nc be 2 since it increments by 1 twice? Thank you.

```
int main()
{
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) 
            ;
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: The [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function is to read *characters*.

Comment: `getchar()` reads ONE char. So this loops counts how many chars you typed whatever they are. If you count a number of things, pmease use an `int` not a `double`.

Comment: The code is just counting characters. A number like 2.3 is three characters

Comment: There is nothing in your code that reads "doubles".

Comment: you type `2`, `.`, `3`, `<enter>`, `1`, `.`, `8`, `<enter>`, `<Ctrl+D>` = 9 *things*, but the `<Ctrl+D>` itself does not reach your `++nc` :)

Comment: https://ideone.com/rTcgCx

Comment: I understand now thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getchar()
```

This function is used to read one character at a time.

As you have typed 8 characters('2','.','3','enter','1','.','8','enter') in total the output is 8.

Comment: `<Ctrl+D>` does not 'reach' the `++nc` statement.

Comment: But isn't nc it's own thing, it's set to 0 and is an incrementer.

Answer (score 1):

Count the characters: '2', '.', '3', 'enter', '1', '.', '8', 'enter'. I get 8.

The `getchar` function gets characters.

The only `double` in your code is `nc` which gets set to zero and then incremented eight times, leaving it with a final value of 8.0, as you see.